# How to read a specific range of lines in an external file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say you have a python file with 50 lines of code in it, and you want to read a specific range lines into a list. If you want to read ALL the lines in the file, you can just use the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/in-python-how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list#):

```
with open('yourfile.py') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

print(content)
```

But what if you want to read a specific range of lines, like reading line 23-27?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
f.readlines(23:27)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close.  `readlines` returns a list and you can slice that, but it's invalid syntax to try and pass the slice directly in the function call.

```
f.readlines()[23:27]
```

If the file is very large, avoid the memory overhead of reading the entire file:

```
start, stop = 23, 27
for i in range(start):
    next(f)
content = []
for i in range(stop-start):
    content.append(next(f))
```

Comment: In my opinion, when one says "I want line 23 to 27", the latter is included. So, the stop should be the stopping point you actually want... +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sublines = content[23:27]
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are lots and lots of lines in your file, I believe you should consider using `f.readline()` (without an `s`) 27 times, and only save your lines starting wherever you want. :)

Else, the other ones solution is what I would have done too (meaning : `f.readlines()[23:28]`. 28, because as far as I remember, outer range is excluded.